# Avoid minor modes from turning off when changing/restarting major mode

Tags: org-mode, minor-mode

Is there a smart way to keep locally enabled minor modes enabled when changing/restarting major modes without adding it to the mode hook or enable it globally?

For instance, if I usually don't use `paredit`, but decide one day I want to try it out, but then want to change my major mode from `emacs-lisp-mode` to `lisp-interaction-mode`. How can I do this without `paredit` being disabled?

More specifically I want this to be the case with an extension I am writing for `org-mode`, where I want a variable to be updated when `org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c` is run, but because `org-mode` in some contexts restarts and thus disables my minor mode, it is unable to do this without **always** being enabled with `org-mode`.

Comment: Not sure there's a good way to do what you're asking, since you're fighting the Emacs ecosystem by not turning on the minor modes in the relevant major mode hooks.  You might be able to build some machinery into `after-change-major-mode-hook`.

Comment: Locally-enabled minor modes are often tied specifically to the major mode. It wouldn't make sense to cause them *all* to remain enabled after a major mode change. Therefore you would need some specific configuration to say "only retain these specific minor modes for these specific major modes" (if it was for *all* major modes you'd be using a *global* minor mode in the first place). And an obvious way to say "use these specific minor modes with these specific major modes" is to use the extremely standard mode-hook approach. So just do that?

Comment: You *might* be looking for the `define-globalized-minor-mode` macro, however, to define a controlling function that determines whether a given buffer-local minor mode will be enabled in *any* given buffer.